# Change ownership of directory owned by root

Tags: files, permissions, directory, ownership

As a non-privileged user, owning a directory on an `EXT4` filesystem where I have all the necessary rights (`rwx`) gives me the possibility to change content and ownership of files (e.g. `vim file` and `:w!`) within it even if they are owned by root and even if I don't have the right to change them (`root:root` and `0644`).

Is that somehow possible with a directory owned by root if that directory is within a directory owned by my non-privileged user?

Comment: What type of filesystem is it?   Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: By the way, guys, the “problem that can’t be reproduced” close reason is for problems *that **the OP** can’t reproduce*.  It is not meant to be used in the case where you, another member of the community, are unable to reproduce the OP’s problem.

Comment: @G-Man yes sure, I edited my question and added the FS-Type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The owner of a directory can change the contents of the directory however they want. Even if there's a file in the directory that the directory owner isn't allowed to write, the directory owner can remove that file and create a new file by the same name.

More generally, if you have write permission to a directory, then you can remove and create files in that directory. Thus you can change files in that directory, not by writing to them if you don't have write permission on the file, but by deleting the existing file and creating a new file by the same name.

If you own a directory `parent` and it contains a subdirectory `child` that is owned by root and you don't have write permission on `child`, then you can't modify files in `child`. However, you can rename `child` and create a new subdirectory called `child`, which will be owned by you and thus can contain whatever you want.

This is why security checks that verify file control (e.g. the sanity checks that OpenSSH makes on private key files) verify the whole directory chain up to the root. Likewise, if you give a user sudo rights to run a file, the whole path to the file should be controlled by root. For example, don't give a user sudo rights to run a program that's under their home directory. (On the other hand, a setuid root program anywhere is fine, because setuid is attached to the file itself, not to its path.) Anyone who controls any intermediate step in the directory path can substitute their own content, not by editing the actual file, but by renaming a directory at the point in the path.

Comment: I gave sudo-rights to a shell-script in `/home/${USER}/rootdir/` (where `rootdir` is owned by `root:root` with `0775`) - so regarding your answer, even that is not secure, because `${USER}` could rename the orginal `rootdir`, create a new directory with the same name `rootdir` and replace the script with it’s own version, which will pertain the same sudo-rights, correct?

Comment: @chevallier You mean you gave a bob the right to run `sudo /home/bob/rootdir/myscript`? Indeed, that's insecure, because bob can do `mv /home/bob/rootdir /home/bob/not.rootdir; mkdir /home/bob/not_rootdir; ln -s /bin/sh /home/bob/rootdir/myscript` and then `sudo /home/bob/rootdir/myscript` will run sh as root.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to replicate your stated premise.

Directory owned by me containing a file owned by root:

```
$ ls -ld mydir mydir/file2
drwxrwxr-x 2 user1 user1 4096 Jan  5 13:52 mydir
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root  root     0 Jan  5 13:52 mydir/file2
```

Attempt to claim ownership of `root`'s file in `mydir`:

```
$ chown user1 mydir/file2
chown: changing ownership of 'mydir/file2': Operation not permitted
```

Comment: Editing the file should also not be permitted. Deleting it however is perfectly permissible.

Comment: It is indeed possible, try `vim file` and then force the write with `:w!`.

Comment: You can't change ownership of the existing file, but you can remove the file and create a new file by the same name and with the same content, owned by you.

Comment: Neither of which are the stated scenario in the original question, since deleting and replacing a file and altering a file (or its properties) are different propositions.